# Underline all of href tag text: issues with having </span><br /><span> inside href tag

Tags: html, css

I have a small problem and can't figure out how to fix it. In my HTML I have an ahref tag with a "/span" tag, a line break, and a new "span" tag within it.

In my css I have a class to make my ahref tags underline when there is a mouse hover.

The one ahref tag with the "/span" "br" "span" in it will not underline at the same time... they will only underline individually when the mouse is hovered over each line. (demo below)

The span classes are for line height adjustments that were needed to line things up correctly with adjacent context.

Simplified HTML:

```
<span class="span1">
    <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">The Google</a><br/><br/>
    <a href="www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">The StackOverFlow</a><br/><br/>
    <a href="www.us.gov" target=_"blank">Important </span><br /><span class="span2"> Information</a></span>
```

Simplified CSS:

```
a, a:link, a:active, a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;    

}

span.span1{
    font-style:normal;  
    font-size:70%;
    line-height: 250%;
}

span.span2{
    font-style:normal;  
    font-size:70%;
    line-height: 100%;

}
```

Any Ideas? Please see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9rFzC/

Comment: this is invalid html syntax. Check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9rFzC/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your html to :

```
<span class="span1">
    <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">The Google</a><br/><br/>
    <a href="www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">The StackOverFlow</a><br/><br/>
    <a href="www.us.gov" target=_"blank"><span>Important </span>

<br /><span class="span2"> Information</span>

</a>
</span>
```

and it should work seamlessly. Basically, fix the missing `<span>` and `</span>` tags.

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9rFzC/2/

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the opening and end tags for the first `span` in your `a` and the closing tag for your container `span.span1`. Just add them and it will work. You cannot nest it like that.

You have also in that link the target declaration wrong, the underscore is part of the value. Seems like a typo.

Answer (score 1):

span is only suppose to be for inline content...

remove span, 
and replace with

```
<div id="whateva">...your links br etc </div>
```

and then

```
#whateva:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
```